# Adding RVM to path Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I'm having difficulty installing rvm and setting the path for it.

```
rvm install ruby
```

This yield "rvm: command not found"

When I `echo $PATH`

This yields "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

So obviously, rvm is not in my path. I see that I have rvm in my "/usr/local/rvm"

However, when I try `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm`

And then .. `rvm install ruby`

Still.. there is no command found.

Here is my .bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm
```

Comment: When you installed RVM, did you restart the terminal? What does your `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bash_profile` file look like?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I included the .bashrc in the post. The .bash_profile is empty. And yes I've restarted the terminal several times

Comment: Usually when you install RVM (it's been a few years for me) it adds a line to your .bashrc/.bash_profile/.profile files that adds RVM to your path. Unless that has changed in recent years, you need it. How did you install RVM?

Comment: Oh! I see you installed RVM for every user on the machine (hence RVM is located in /usr/local). Try adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm` to your .bashrc file.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yeah I tried that as well as running that command through the terminal

Comment: Is the RVM executable actually `/usr/local/rvm` or is the file path `/usr/local/rvm` a directory. Silly question I know, but I assumed it was a directory and the executable was something like `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`

Comment: @GregBurghardt The path `usr/local/rvm` is a directory

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact command line output of `rvm install ruby`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I've now used rvm to install ruby correctly. I believe the problem was that after running the commmand `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`. I needed to run an additional command `source /home/jack/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: Ah, ok. In fact, you should probably source that script in your .bashrc file. That's the line that installing RVM for a single user will add automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I just added `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` on Ubuntu 14.04LTS 
in `/etc/environment`.

```
# cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the line below at the end of my `~/.zshrc` solved the issue.

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 0):

i had struggled on this a lot. Sometimes the location can also be /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm.

Hope this helps the other users finding the same problem.